# Stranded preposition: Meine Familie geht da echt gut mit um

Tags: meaning-in-context, colloquial, grammaticality

The following is from a YouTube video:

> "Was sagen deine Familie und Freunde dazu, dass du YouTube-Videos drehst?"
>   "Also meine Familie *geht **da** echt gut **mit** um* also die haben mich sogar da drin unterstützt."

I found in the dictionaries that there is a construction "mit jemandem/etwas irgendwie umgehen".

However, in the original sentence the ***mit*** is not followed by any object. Can someone please explain the grammar in this sentence. And also, what does ***da*** mean here?

Comment: the da in this sentece stands for the "dass du youtube videos drehst".  it's hard to explain for me. i guess you can compare it to something like this .  how do your parents deal with your drinking / smoking?  they deal with IT openly.  this IT reflects whatever it was about in the sentence before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It occurs in colloquial speech. It's a split-up of *damit*, which at the same time utilizes *da* as a filler (meaning *there* / *in this matter/situation*).

> Meine Familie geht damit echt gut um. (My family deals with it really well.)
>
> Da geht meine Familie echt gut mit um.
>
> Meine Familie geht da echt gut mit um.

(The expression 'mit etwas umgehen' was adopted from the realms of psychological counseling, figuratively meaning 'to deal/cope with sth.', e.g. stress, disappointments, traumatic incidents ...)

Comment: You can also use `damit` without splitting it up: "*Meine Familie geht damit gut um.*".

Comment: "fillers" have no meaning... the da is not a filler but a regular part of the sentence. Without it the sentence wouldn't be grammatical anymore. Also, I'd like to add that this is more than colloquial by now... it is a new feature but it is gaining ground every day

Answer (score 4):

I think I found the answer myself in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preposition_stranding#R-pronouns)'s article on preposition stranding:

> Some regional varieties of German show the same phenomenon with da(r)- and wo(r)- forms. For example:
> Standard German requires *Ich kann mir **davon** nichts kaufen*.
> literally, *I can me **therefrom** nothing buy.*
> i.e., *I can't buy anything with this*.
> Some dialects permit *Ich kann mir **da** nichts **von** kaufen*.
> literally, *I can me **there-**[clipped] nothing **from** buy.*
> i.e., *I can't buy anything with this.*
> Alternatively, one might also say ***Da** kann ich mir nichts **von** kaufen.*
> literally, ***There-**[clipped] can I me nothing **from** buy.*
> i.e., *I can't buy anything with this.*

Would be nice to know what dialects exactly, though. Because it really seemed to me that the speaker was speaking standard German.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's so much a dialect but rather a colloquial practice. It's still a standard word that's just used in a nonstandard way. That sort of thing can happen pretty much anywhere.

Comment: @Kevin: No, it is clearly associated with northern Germany.

Comment: @chirlu I just meant that using standard words in nonstandard ways can happen pretty much anywhere. That's why I said "that sort of thing", meaning that changing words around doesn't necessarily make it a dialect as much as a colloquial practice. Specific words that are changed may only occur in certain regions, as in this case. But I was just addressing the use of the word "dialect".

Comment: @Kevin: OK, we can agree that "dialect" is not the best word here.

Answer (score 3):

Your explanation from Wikipedia is correct.

The speaker is probably somewhere from northern Germany. There, most people speak in a way that sounds very close standard German (and they normally think it is). Splitting »damit« and others is one of the exceptions.